# What is the correct syntax for jq?

Tags: json, jq

Is there a commandline documentation to use `jq`? I am currently running this command:

```
%jq% -f JSON.txt -r ".sm_api_content"
```

It is supposed to read from `JSON.txt` and to output the value of `sm_api_content` (which is a string).

But I am getting this error:

```
jq: error: Could not open file .sm_api_content: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Try `man jq`...

Comment: Or google "jq" and pick the first result...

Comment: @l'L'l Sorry but I am on windows :(

Comment: @robertklep It links to jq's homepage

Comment: @TheDcoder which links to the manual. You start your question with "Is there a documentation to use `jq`?"

Comment: @robertklep Ah! its not my question... wasthishelpful edited the question, my original question was different, please check the edit!

Comment: *Proof read before posting* will stop people mauling your question - See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You left out the error; you just posted a duplicate of the command. And what are the `%`s for?

Comment: @chepner Oh! oops! copy and paste mistake... `%jq%` is a variable, it contains the path of jq's executable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-f` is for specifying a filename to read your "filter" from - the filter in this case being `.sm_api_content`

It sounds as if you just want to run `jq` without `-f`, e.g.

```
jq -r .sm_api_content JSON.txt
```